# Listfragment listview selected item not hilighted when back

Tags: android, android-listview, android-listfragment

I am using listfragment and fragments. Left side having listfragment and right panel details fragment. Now the problem is whenever i am selecting the list item from the listfragment the right panel shows the details of particular item but listfragment listview selected item is not highlighted.

Can any one help on this?

Answer (score 1):

if you want to hi-light particular row when you touch that row then change it's background

```
getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
    rowView.setBackgroundResrouce(R.color.some_color);
```

Comment: whenever i am selecting item it is highlighted but from this view i have button and clicking this going to another screen now i am coming back to listview here i am not getting highlighted which i was selected last.

Comment: in that case you have to preserve the selected state and when you go back to your first activity use that state

Comment: can you please tell me how to do that?

Comment: when you click on row save its position in some static int variable and when you reopen activity just check that static int value now you have to hi-light the row which is in the position you get from this variable if you need help let me know

Comment: Thanks for your help. Now this is working fine but i want to refresh the listfragment listview. Do you have any idea?